# In search of Latex Template

Tags: overleaf, templates

For my master thesis I am looking for a nice latex template and come across the following paper which I really liked.
However, I could not find the template online. Therefore, I am wondering if somebody knows the template.
Added pictures to showcase the template:

[image: Table of Contents]

[image: Start of section]

[image: Somewhere in the middle of the section]

Already tried to recreate it with fancyhdr and fncychap, but did not yield a good result.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please add your attempts to your question.

Comment: How about this? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=thesis+template+overleaf&atb=v314-1&ia=web